# Creating Java Rechargeable Battery Tester

Tags: java

I can't figure out how to make the code for this tester part of my program.
I provided the Battery class I made but need help making the tester to run everything.

```
package batterytester;

public class Battery {
    // identifies variables and cap means capacity
    double fullCharge = 2500;
    double batteryCap;

    Battery() {
        fullCharge = 2500;
    }

    public Battery(double cap) {

        batteryCap = cap;
        fullCharge = cap;

    }

    void charge() {
        batteryCap = fullCharge;
    }

    void drain(double amount) {
        batteryCap = batteryCap - amount;
    }

    double getRemainingCapacity() {
        return batteryCap;
    }
}
```

Comment: Help of what sort?  What have you tried so far? What problem(s) are you having?

Comment: What tester? Which test framework? Are you looking for homework help?

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at any [tutorials on Junit](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/JUnit/article.html)? Your code is very testable with simple `Assert` statements used within `@Test` unit test methods. Here are some samples:

```
@Test
public void testChargeOrDrain() { // poor form to have multiple assertions but you get the idea...
    Battery battery = new Battery();
    assertNotNull("Expected a new battery object", battery);
    assertEquals("Expected a full charge of 2500", 2500, battery.getRemainingCapacity();
    battery.drain(500);
    assertEquals("Expected a partial charge of 500", 500, battery.getRemainingCapacity();
    battery.charge();
    assertEquals("Expected a full charge of 2500", 2500, battery.getRemainingCapacity();
}
```

Thorough unit tests will help smoke out bugs and anomalies, and verify each functional piece of your code works as intended. For example, what happens to your `drain()` function if I supply a negative value? :)